# is there any mongo db query to only add new elements the nested elements by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

my data structure is and products elements all tags in empty

I need to add a value to mongo db inner object with array element without looking at other value. Can some one advice to do this.

```
[
    {
      "item": "journal",
      "id": 11,
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "p one",
          "tags": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "item": "notebook",
      "id": 14,
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 4010,
          "name": "item-five",
          "tags": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and I want to add tag in products elements with match product id '4010', so the expected response should be like

```
[
    {
      "item": "journal",
      "id": 11,
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "p one",
          "tags": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "item": "notebook",
      "id": 14,
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 4010,
          "name": "item-five",
          "tags": [
            {
              "id": 21,
              "key": "tag-one",
              "name": "tag-one",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `arrayFilter` option https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array

Something like this might do the trick.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
      { },
      { $push: { "products.$[x].tags":  {
              "id": 21,
              "key": "tag-one",
              "name": "tag-one",
            } } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "x.id": 4010 }] }
    );
```